# Problems with NSNotificationCenter and loading the UIViewControlletr

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsthread, nsnotificationcenter

I have a `UIViewController` with button that brings another `UIViewController`. with clicking on button , as shown in my `NSLog`, and when this is done, I want to send a notification to load another `viewcontroller` . Well, although it seems everything is done right, somehow it does not work and the `UIViewController` not appear. Here is the code:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(infoPage:)
                                                  name:@"InfoPage" object:nil ];



-(void) infoPage:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Code executing in Thread %@",[NSThread currentThread] );

    InfoCtrol *i = [[InfoCtrol alloc] init];
     i.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:i animated:YES];
}
```

my tabbaritem button

```
-(void)info {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"InfoPage"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:nil];
     NSLog(@"test not");
}
```

I think my  problem is that: It's not in a mainThread but I do n't know how should I solved that:

I also used this but it didn't bring the UIViewController:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(test) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)test{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"InfoPage"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:nil];
}
```

If I just put this code in button, it displays the `UIViewController`, but I want to use `NSNotificationCenter`

```
InfoCtrol *i = [[InfoCtrol alloc] init];
     i.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:i animated:YES];
```

My Log:

```
Code executing in Thread <NSThread: 0x1fd7c7e0>{name = (null), num = 1}
```

**Update:**

```
 How should i remove last thread from mainThread
```

Comment: All UIKit things happen on the main thread, and you have to purposely move to another thread using e.g. Grand Central Dispatch, so it's unlikely that being on another thread is the issue. There is a class method on `NSThread` called `isMainThread` that you could use to check, though.

Comment: What controllers are these code snippets in? You should describe what controllers you have and where all this code resides.

Comment: make sure `self.navigationController` is not `nil`

Comment: @GuoLuchuan how should I test that

Comment: @MaxGabriel would you please show me with some code

Comment: add `if(self.navigationController == nil) NSLog(@"it must be wrong here");` before you push ViewController

Comment: @adam I really don't think this has to do with threading. If you upload the code to github or something, I will look at it and find the problem.

Comment: @GuoLuchuan no it's not nil

Comment: At what point are you adding your view controller as an observer for the NSNotificationCenter?
And are you completely sure your test method is being executed?

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo yes for both questions

Comment: I was not expecting a boolean return type for the first question.

Edit: try to make your actions be performed on main thread using this code:

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  /*your code to push the view controller here*/
 });

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo sorry what do you mean at what point? this NSNotificationCenter works for one of my view that it's not contation tab bar but in a page with tabbar it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use a notification here, when you can perform the action directly without issue.  But a simple thing you can do in notification methods that need to update UI is to just have them call themselves on the main thread if they're not already running on that thread:

```
-(void)myNotificationMethod:(NSNotification*)note {
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myNotificationMethod:)
                               withObject:note
                            waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

    // ... do some UI stuff
    InfoCtrol *i = [[InfoCtrol alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:i animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @SeamusCambell Still problem, it's not load the uiviewcontroller, reason for using NSNotification centre:I have alot info button, do you know why I have this null for name?: <NSThread: 0x1dd2cad0>{name = (null), num = 1}

Comment: `name` is just a property that can be set on threads.  It's not required and I presume it's just a convenience.  It sounds most likely to me that `self.navigationController` is `nil` here for some reason.

Comment: I forgot to say one thing, when I call the class in normal way I have tabbar item in my view that I will hide them,it mean's that tabbar view it's over my view, but with NSSnotificationCenter the view cannot come